# Setting Google Analytics tracker clientId in form

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I have a form that does a GET to another site and want to use the `?_ga=` tracker ID when the form is submitted. I have this tracker clientId working correctly on regular links, but somehow cannot get it to work on below form.

```
<form action="" method="get" name="iform" id="iform" target="_blank">
    <div class="form-items">
        <div class="form-item fas-feedback date date-1">
            <label for="DateIn">From</label>
            <input type="text" class="check-date-from" id="check-in" name="DateIn" readonly placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-item fas-feedback date date-2">
            <label for="DateOut">Till</label>
            <input type="text" class="check-date-to" id="check-out" readonly name="DateOut" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-action long-transition">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the script:

```
var clientId;
$(document).ready(function() {
    ga(function(tracker) {
        clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
    });

    $("#iform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uri = 'https://engines.hoteliers.com/en/3456789/whitelabelplus/getdata/arrival/'+$("#check-in").val()+'/departure/'+$("#check-out").val()+'/type/roomonly/?clientId='+clientId;
        window.open(uri, '_blank');
        return false;
    })
});
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by not working? is `clientId` wrong? or empty or what?

Comment: The clientId is not empty and the URL is created with a correct `?clientId=2345678`, it only doesnt set the cookie correct into `?_ga=90876543` while the regular links work fine with it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#iform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var clientId = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');      
        var uri = 'https://engines.hoteliers.com/en/3456789/whitelabelplus/getdata/arrival/'+$("#check-in").val()+'/departure/'+$("#check-out").val()+'/type/roomonly/?clientId='+clientId;
        window.open(uri, '_blank');
        return false;
    });
});
```